# How Server Knows Which Framework is Working

Tags: java, spring

I have asked this question in an interview that

> There are many framework like spring,struts,struts2,wicket but how server knows that which framework is currently working?

Comment: I don't understend your point. Server doesn't know anything about frameworks. For him he runs just code (Java code for Java server etc.).

Answer (score 3):

The server does not have to. It just follows the Java EE specs. It's upto the framework to align itself to it.

If you coded in various frameworks you will find that you need to tell a specific servlet in your web.xml -- like in Struts-1 you pin ActionServlet, in Wicket it's WicketServlet, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

For every Java webapp, there is a deployment descriptor file named [`web.xml`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html), which defines (among other things) the servlets and servlet filters of which the webapp is composed.

If your application uses the a certain framework, you have to add some framework-specific entries to that file.

Most web frameworks are based on one central servlet or servlet filter that delegates calls to application classes according to the framework's conventions and configuration.